# Dearth of research on treating Periodic Limb Movement Disorder (PLMD) with Baclofen

Tags: neurology

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6721446

The above study from 1984 at Stanford found that oral administration of baclofen somewhat improved sleep in patients with PLM-associated arousals. The results seem fairly positive, with the finding essentially that although baclofen increased the *number* of PLMs, it decreased their amplitude, and decreased the length of the arousals associated with PLMs.

My question then is why does there seem to be no follow-up research on the treatment of PLMD (i.e. arousals caused by PLMs) with baclofen? I understand that RLS (Restless Leg Syndrome) is accompanied by PLMS in about 80% of RLS cases, and since dopaminergics and anti-convulsants are generally more effective treatment for RLS than are muscle relaxants (like baclofen) the research on RLS and baclofen is not extensive. But in cases of PLM-associated arousals unaccompanied by sensations of restlessness (RLS), why is there no further research on the seemingly promising treatment of baclofen?